# How to pass an object from a carousel view to a custom control in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I currently have a carousel view that makes use of an object in the binding context to obtain a list of instances of the ListItem property. The binding to MyList for the CarouselView is working fine and I am able to scroll left and right for every item in my list. The trouble that I'm having is that while the CustomControl is being loaded, it is not receiving the ListItem that will fit in the Item property. So, the this.Item property in CustomControl is just returning null.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
                    <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
                        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <controls:CustomControl Item="{Binding}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

                    </CarouselView>

                </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class HomeView : ContentPage
    {
        private ListContainer vm; 
        
        public HomeView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                vm = DiContainer.Resolve<ListContainer>();
                await vm.Initialise();

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    this.BindingContext = vm;
                });

            });
        }
    }
```

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class CustomControl : ContentView
    {

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Item), 
            typeof(ListItem), typeof(CustomControl), default(ListItem),BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public ListItem Item
        {
            get => (ListItem)GetValue(ItemProperty);
            set => SetValue(ItemProperty, value);
        }

        public CustomControl ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You shouldn’t assume that properties of a class have been set when it’s constructor executes

Comment: and, by default the control should inherit the `BindingContext` of its parent, so explicitly setting it shouldn't be necessary

Comment: @Jason I've checked in the debugger and the properties are being set.

Comment: that is not what you stated in your question - "this.Item property in CustomControl is just returning null."

Comment: What I mean is that when I check the property 'MyList' it does have objects of type ListItem in there. When I try and assign it to a CustomControl in line '<controls:CustomControl Item="{Binding}"/>', the property Item is found to be null, despite there being ListItems present in MyList.

Comment: and what I mean is that you assign `BindingContext = this.Item;` **in the constructor**, which runs **before** property values have been assigned, so that will set `BindingContext` to `null`.  Try just removing that line.

Comment: Just gave that a shot, it doesn't seem to fix it, but I see your point, thanks.

Comment: @Renma Went through your question and am not sure what exactly you need, Can you summarise precisely what is not working and be as specific and concise as possible?

Comment: @FreakyAli I'm trying to set the "Item" property so that it holds an instance of ListItem that was defined in the binding context.

Comment: @Renma I also create a custom control and put it to `CarouselView.ItemTemplate`. It works well and data can display. What is bound to the things in your CustomControl.xaml?  Could you provide the code of your CustomControl.xaml?